# Replace value & save file during reading CSV file (C#)

Tags: c#, replace, stream, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm reading csv file:

```
string line;

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.ToString());

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string col1 = line.Split(',')[10]; //old value
    col1 = "my value"; //new value
}

sr.Close();
sr.Dispose();
```

I want to replace old value by the new.

Then I need to save the file with the changes.

How can I do that?

Comment: Side note: `using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.ToString())) {...}` is far better (no resource leakage on exception, more readable and maintable) then explit `Dispose` call

Comment: Do you want to same modified values into the *same* file?

Comment: exactly: open file, take value and replace by new, save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using `File` class instead of `Stream`s and `Reader`s. *Linq* is very convenient when querying data:

```
var modifiedData = File
  .ReadLines(file.ToString())
  .Select(line => line.Split(',')) 
  .Select(items => {
     //TODO: put relevant logic here: given items we should return csv line
     items[10] = "my value";

     return string.Join(",", items);
   })
  .ToList(); // <- we have to store modified data in memory

File.WriteAllLines(file.ToString(), modifiedData);
```

Another possibility (say, when initial file is too long to fit memory) is to save the modified data into a *temporary file* and then `Move` it:

```
 var modifiedData = File
  .ReadLines(file.ToString())
  .Select(line => line.Split(',')) 
  .Select(items => {
     //TODO: put relevant logic here: given items we should return csv line
     items[10] = "my value";

     return string.Join(",", items);
   });

 string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.tmp");

 File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, modifiedData);

 File.Delete(file.ToString());
 File.Move(tempFile, file.ToString());
```

Comment: thank you @Dmitry, I will try to use first mode. As I have some logic inside Stream I need to little modify code. Anyway thank you for example!

Comment: when write it to **StreamWriter :  sw.WriteLine(modifiedData)**; Im getting System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.String,System.String]....but how to get a Value?

Comment: `modifiedData` is `IEnumerable<string>`, not a *single* `string`. You can put a *loop*, e.g. `foreach (var line in modifiedData) {sw.WriteLine(line);}`

Comment: @4est: you can read the last line with a help of `Last()` or `LastOrDefault()`, e.g. `string lastLine =  modifiedData.Last();`

Answer (score 0):

Reading an entire file at once is memory-expensive. Not to mention creating its parallel copy. Using streams can fix it. Try this:

```
void Modify()
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        string line;
        long position;

        while ((line = fs.ReadLine(out position)) != null)
        {
            var tmp = line.Split(',');
            tmp[1] = "00"; // new value
            var newLine = string.Join(",", tmp);
            fs.WriteLine(position, newLine);
        }
    }
}
```

with extensions:

```
static class FileStreamExtensions
{
    private static readonly char[] newLine = Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray();
    private static readonly int length = Environment.NewLine.Length;
    private static readonly char eof = '\uFFFF';

    public static string ReadLine(this FileStream fs, out long position)
    {
        position = fs.Position;
        var chars = new List<char>();
        char c;
        while ((c = (char)fs.ReadByte()) != eof && (chars.Count < length || !chars.Skip(chars.Count - 2).SequenceEqual(newLine)))
        {
            chars.Add(c);
        }
        fs.Position--;

        if (chars.Count == 0)
            return null;

        return new string(chars.ToArray());
    }

    public static void WriteLine(this FileStream fs, long position, string line)
    {
        var bytes = line.ToCharArray().Concat(newLine).Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();
        fs.Position = position;
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

The shortcoming is you must keep your values the same length. E.g. `999` and `__9` are both of length 3. Fixing this makes things much more complicated, so I'd leave it this way.

[Full working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2rsbGS)